# The partial derivative of A tensor product A with respect to A

Tags: partial-derivative, tensor-products

From what I understand of taking partial derivatives of tensor products, the following should be correct:

$\frac{\partial (m \otimes m)}{\partial m} = \frac{\partial m}{\partial m} \otimes m + m \otimes \frac{\partial m}{\partial m}$

$\frac{\partial (m \otimes m)}{\partial m} = I \otimes m + m \otimes I$

where m is a 6x1 vector and $m \otimes m$ is a 6x6 tensor.

My questions are:

1. What would be the dimension of $I$? From the operation, it should be 6 x 1, but how can an identity tensor be a vector of size 6x1?
2. If $I$ should just be treated like a numerical 1, the expression becomes $m + m$ which also doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I$ is has dimensions "$6 \times 6$". In other words, $I \otimes m$ is a rank 3 tensor, with dimensions $6 \times 6 \times 6$. So $I$ is **not** literally to be treated as $1$, though it does act trivially on the space that $m$ lives in.

It might help to clarify with an example. Suppose that $m \in \mathbb{R}^6$ (I'm assuming you have some kind of vector space similar to Euclidean space if you're doing calculus in it).

Pick an orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^6$ for $\mathbb{R}^6$. Then $I = \sum_{i=1}^6 e_i \otimes e_i$. So really you have
$$ I \otimes m = \sum_{i=1}^6 e_i \otimes e_i \otimes m $$
which is a third order tensor. You can think of $(I \otimes m)_{ijk}$ as having three indices, each spanning from $1$ to $6$.

**EDIT**:
Here's some more clarity on if you can simplify $I \otimes m + m \otimes I$. The summary is that you can't really simplify this expression any further, but if you expand $m$ in the orthonormal basis as $m = \sum_{i=1}^6 m_i e_i$ then you have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial (m \otimes m)}{\partial m} &= I \otimes m + m \otimes I\\
&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^6 e_i \otimes e_i \otimes m \right) + \left(\sum_{i=1}^6 m \otimes e_i \otimes e_i \right)\\
&= \left(\sum_{i,j=1}^6 m_j \, e_i \otimes e_i \otimes e_j \right) + \left(\sum_{i,j=1}^6 m_j\, e_j \otimes e_i \otimes e_i \right)\\
&= \sum_{i,j=1}^6 m_j \left( e_i \otimes e_i \otimes e_j + e_j \otimes e_i \otimes e_i \right)
\end{align}$$
Notice that $e_i \otimes e_i \otimes e_j + e_j \otimes e_i \otimes e_i$ can only be simplified when $i = j$, but if for example $i=1$ and $j=2$, then
$$ e_1 \otimes e_1 \otimes e_2 \ne e_2 \otimes e_1 \otimes e_1 $$

Comment: Thanks a lot! That explains it very well. A followup question: does that make the partial derivative a 6x6x6 tensor also? The next operation is a dot product with another 6x6 tensor, does that mean I did something wrong in this derivation since I can't dot 6x6 with 6x6x6? The goal is to implement this calculation numerically, and I am confused at how to program a 6x6 dot 6x6x6.

Comment: The partial derivative (really it's a type of **gradient** here) takes $m \otimes m$ from a $6 \times 6$ tensor up to a $6 \times 6 \times 6$ tensor. In other words, it increases the tensorial order. This is pretty much by definition, since one usually defines $\frac{\partial f}{\partial m} = \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial m_i} \otimes e_i$. For your second question, you certainly **can** dot a $6 \times 6$ with a $6 \times 6 \times 6$. You'll end up with a rank one tensor. It might be more helpful if you posted another question detailing what exactly you're confused about there.

Comment: For the record though, "einsum" in python probably does exactly what you want. The "dot product" really becomes tensor contraction in certain indices.

Comment: I think I understand now. dot product is just a reduction of rank. I can apply that definition to the rest of this work. There is a lot more to this equation, I will post another question if I get stuck again.